# API definition is not updated during the custom API connector deployment by using `originalSwaggerUrl` on Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have an ARM template to deploy a custom connector (or an update) on the Azure pipeline,

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        ...
        "swaggerSpec": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "http://someapi/v1/swagger/docs/v1"
        }
        ...
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connectorName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                ...
                "apiType": "rest",
                "apiDefinitions": {
                    "originalSwaggerUrl": "[parameters('swaggerSpec')]"
                }
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

This can be deployed successfully(with no errors), but the API definition is not updated to the latest. Not sure what happened or is it correct that I'm using `originalSwaggerUrl`?

Cheers

Comment: have you tried the `modifiedSwaggerUrl` property ? it is possible that if nothing has changed in term of ARM properties it doesnt do anything

Comment: @Thomas I have tried only `modifiedSwaggerUrl` and still didn’t update the definition, but just realised that I may need to use both. But the URLs should be the same actually. Will try tomorrow. Cheers

Comment: @Thomas Tried `"apiDefinitions": { "originalSwaggerUrl": "[parameters('swaggerSpec')]", "modifiedSwaggerUrl": "[parameters('swaggerSpec')]" },` but still not getting the definition updated.

Comment: Do you have access to the swagger file in your pipeline ? there is a `swagger` property that accept the json api definition so you could use that as well ? with bicep you could use the [loadJsonContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-files#loadjsoncontent) function to inject the data. When i was trying from azure portal, i think the url is more an import functionality then if you hit the save button, it will pass the swagger json inside this `swagger` property.

Comment: @Thomas I used to use powershell to download the JSON definition and pass it to the template as an object. However, it no longer works anymore. That's why I changed to this way to do the deployment. Will try your way tomorrow. Thanks, mate.

Comment: @Thomas `loadJsonContent` works and I also tried `json` by passing in a json string works as well. I'll accept your answer if you post your answer. Thanks, mate.

Comment: Also I saw that there a `etag` top level property. I was wondering if you use a random string every deployment it will force an update ? something to try out ^^

Comment: @Thomas I have already used the `etag`, it seems that the `apiDefinitions` property is not for what I using here, but not too much information about it.

Comment: added some other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/customapis?pivots=deployment-language-bicep), you could use the `swagger` property:

> **Name**: swagger
> **Description**: The JSON representation of the swagger
> **Value**: For Bicep, you can use the [any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-any) function.

If you have access to the swagger file locally, you have few options

1. Pass the json definition as an object parameter:

   ```bicep
   param connectorName string
   param location string
   param swagger object

   resource customApi 'Microsoft.Web/customApis@2016-06-01' = {
     name: connectorName
     location: location
     properties: {
       ...
       apiType: 'apiType'
       swagger: swagger
       ...
     }
   }
   ```

   Then you can deploy your template like that (using az cli and powershell here):

   ```
   $swaggerPath="full/path/of/the/swagger/file.json"
   az deployment group create `
     --resource-group "resource group name" `
     --template-file "full/path/of/the/main.bicep" `
     --parameters connectorName="connector name" `
     --parameters location="resource location" `
     --parameters swagger=@$swaggerPath
   ```
2. Use the Bicep [`loadJsonContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-files#loadjsoncontent)

   > The maximum allowed size of the file is 1,048,576 characters, including line endings.

   ```bicep
   param connectorName string
   param location string

   var swagger = loadJsonContent('path/to/swagger/file/')

   resource customApi 'Microsoft.Web/customApis@2016-06-01' = {
     name: connectorName
     location: location
     properties: {
       ...
       apiType: 'apiType'
       swagger: swagger
       ...
     }
   }
   ```